# Изменение background-a меню

Tags: xml, android, java

Доброго времени суток! Мне нужно изменить фон своего меню, порывшись в гугле я решил реализовать это так:

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    if (!getUserId().equalsIgnoreCase("_myface"))
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.photo_menu, menu);
    setMenuBackground();
}

protected void setMenuBackground() {
    getActivity().getLayoutInflater().setFactory(new LayoutInflater.Factory() {
        @Override
        public View onCreateView (String name, Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
            if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("com.android.internal.view.menu.IconMenuItemView")) {
                try {
                    // Ask our inflater to create the view
                    LayoutInflater f = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
                    final View view = f.createView(name, null, attrs);
                    // Kind of apply our own background
                    new Handler().post( new Runnable() {
                        public void run () {
                            view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.new_menu_add_photos);
                        }
                    });
                    return view;
                }
                catch (InflateException e) {
                }
                catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
    });
}
```

Но приложение падает и выдаёт такую ошибку:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: A factory has already been set on this LayoutInflater
```

xml:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:id="@+id/actionAdd"
     android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
     android:icon="@drawable/menu_add_selector">
     <menu>
         <item android:id="@+id/actionTake" android:icon="@drawable/new_menu_icon_make_photo" android:title="@string/camera"/>
         <item android:id="@+id/actionSelect" android:icon="@drawable/new_menu_icon_from_gallery" android:title="@string/gallery"/>
     </menu>
```

</item>
</menu>

Может кто-то уже сталкивался с подобным? Как эту проблему можно решить? Спасибо за внимание.

Comment: а сразу в хмл установить нужный фон не подходит?

Answer (score 1):

Понимаю что некропост, но может поможет кому.

```
boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.menu_background));
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Где в menu_background текстура фона меню.

Comment: За некропост даже некрознак бывает )

Answer (score 0):

Почему бы просто не создать colors.xml и в нём прописать

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="backdround">#CEF6F5</color>
</resources>
```

а потом в твоём layout, что принадлежит менюхе прописать это

```
android:background="@color/backdround"
```

так поменяется цвет заднего фона = )

Comment: у менюхи нет лэйаута,есть только стандартная менюшная xml

Comment: в менюшном xml параметр этот можно установить?

Comment: к сожалению нельзя

Comment: кинь код своего леяута

Comment: да, тут код нужно смотреть xml файла